# Tell me if this journey builder set up is correct

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, journeybuilder

I currently have a basic journey setup. The entry trigger is salesforce data.

After 7 days I want to send a discount code email to anyone who did not purchase a ticket.

The way I'm doing this now is using a daily Automation that fires a Query to refresh a data extension with anyone who purchased a ticket, then sends the email and exclude that data extension.

So my plan was to take that same data extension, create an attribute group in contact builder, and use it in the Goals section of Journey Builder. If they appear in that Data Extension, they will meet the goal and exit the journey. The part that concerns me is the timing. That Data Extension will be refreshed every morning, but the Journey is firing real time. every subscriber will by default get a promo code email after 7 days, except those that are ejected. My data extension will grab ticket purchasers from the past 14 days just to be safe. But I feel like I am missing something here.... I just don't know what. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a quick read, the edge case I see are those who make a purchase on Day 7 before receiving the email with the discount code.  If it's possible to figure out when people typically purchase you might find that this edge case is worth the risk.